# Placing Select Folders Under Version Control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN repository on my hosted server (linux), and I need to do local work on them on my windows machine (tortoise svn installed).  To simplify my question, the dir structure looks like:

```
root
|--------sub1
|--------sub2
|--------sub3
...
|--------subN
```

with additional subfolders under each subX.  Say I only want certain sub-subfolders of "sub1" and "sub3" under version control.  But on windows, when I commit a change with tortoisesvn, I still want to be able to right click the root folder, hit commit, and have any changes that exist anywhere under root in any selected folders to be committed.   The problem is, I think using ignore would be very cumbersome, since there would be so many folders to ignore, at different levels of structure.

So basically, I want to put the whole thing under version control, and then tell svn "ok, now ignore everything except X and Y".  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Jonah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up the information on [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) in the [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.com).

This will take a bit of work, and I don't know if TortoiseSVN supports this, but this will do what you want.

When you do your initial checkout, you should use the `--depth=empty` option. This will checkout your repository, but without any folders in the working directory. Then, for each folder you do want, you need to do a `svn update --set-depth infinity`. That will update that one folder and keep it updated.

```
$ svn co --depth=empty http://svn/repos/project/trunk myproj
checked out revision 123133

$ cd myproj
$ svn update --set-depth=infinity sub1
[yadda, yadda, yadda]
$ svn update --set-depth=infinity sub2
[yadda, yadda, yadda]
```

If you don't mind a bunch of empty folders in your working directory, you could use `immediates` instead of `empty`. That will checkout everything in that level, but not in subdirectories. You'll see folders, but they won't contain anything. Then, you can do `svn update` on the folders you want. But, you if you don't use `--set-depth` your subfolders will have problems updating later on.

Comment: this is exactly the solution i need, but i don't think tortoisesvn supports --set-depth on the update command

Answer (score 0):

With CVS (the predecessor to SVN) there was a .cvsIgnore file.  I thinik that there is no .svnIgnore file with SVN, but I know there is svn:ignore functionality.  Try a google search of ".svnIgnore file" to see if any of that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With Svn, you can't add stuff under a folder that is not under version control, without adding the root dir.

svn:ignore will ignore files (from a `svn status`) according to your pattern. ie. `svn propset svn:ignore "*.xml" folder/` would ignore any xml files (NOT under version control) under the folder directory. So it would not help you because, once you add a file and try to ignore it, any subsequent modification would still be taken in consideration for a commit.

Because tortoise svn automaticely add any created files (using the gui), you would have to revert modifications of folders you want to exclude.

Hope this helps

Comment: so how would you solve my problem? Manually ignore everything before I do the initial import?

Comment: Add every folder you want, then set the ignore to the ones you wish to ignore. FYI: you should set the ignore on the parent folder of the folder to ignore. ie. if you want to ignore the folder `dir` in sub1, you would use: `svn propset svn:ignore "dir" sub1`

Comment: Sparse directories would be a better solution. see "David W." answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to ignore all and then not ignore specific ones.  You will have to ignore the ones you want to ignore.  The command I use for this is:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "sub1 sub2 sub3 ... subN" ./rootDir
```

You will have to import the directories you want in svn, then run the propset, then commit. Then add the actual ignored directories to the rootDir.

**EDIT:** Mistake in the above.  It should be:

```
 svn propset svn:ignore -F file.txt ./rootDir
```

Reason is that for multiple properties given to propset it needs them to be newline separated. See [here](http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/12/10/how-to-make-subversion-ignore-files-and-folders/).

So, for your problem above I would do:

```
ls > file.txt
```

Then erase the directories that you DO want version controlled, then call the svn propset from above with that file.

Comment: SuperJames, thanks.  But why do I have to wait until the propset is run before I add the folders to rootDir? Let's assume the entire directory structure is already in place and I don't want to move anything.  Could I create the ignore list first, and then do the complete import?

Comment: You could do that. I just put it that way so that if you have not imported it yet, it will ignore the directories when you do the first commit.